# Does Stack Overflow have any way of preventing vote trolls?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, voting

On three consecutive questions, I have been downvoted into negative values, even though the question was clear. When a reason was provided for the down votes, the reason was nonsense (BS) or simply illustrated lack of understanding of entire concept (meaning they shouldn't have even bothered looking at the question if they don't have knowledge in that area). Is there a way to flag vote trolls, or somehow prevent it?

Perhaps have the ability to report them and the question being trolled for review by higher authority? An appeal to have the down votes removed?  Having negative votes on a question I notice seems to reduce the chance of the question being answered, and definitely has a negative effect on reputation points, so I think there should be a way to appeal that, or people can simply go around downvoting things for the fun of it simply because they have enough reputation points?

Comment: I've looked at your profile, and I see absolutely no evidence whatsoever of anything remotely similar to "troll voting". Whatever that might mean. The questions that were down voted seem, to me, to have earned those votes. Additionally; as of the time of this comment, I see a grand-total of **4** down votes on your entire profile (including deleted content)

Comment: I would add that ranting about downvotes in the answer you posted to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24335462/how-do-i-get-css-validator-jar-to-process-a-css-file-in-a-file-system-as-opposed) isn't a great idea... You seem to be taking downvotes personally - they aren't personal. They're purely a reflection of what the community thinks about the *content* of the question.

Comment: @JonK I have *[no idea](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/24413353/revisions)* what you are talking about... ;-)

Comment: I think the question was perfectly clear.  If not, at least specify why, don't downvote and leave it as is.

Comment: I think you might have a misunderstanding about what we expect here from questions. Please don't feel badly about that; we are *very different* than any other forum out there. I recommend reading this for more: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @cluemein Leaving a comment when downvoting is not mandatory for a variety of reasons.  Try not to take the downvotes too personally.

Comment: And the reason I say vote trolling was because it only started on a specific series of questions, in a certain time frame.  I have gotten down votes before, but not like this, where even improvements and clarifications have no effect, and no one offers suggestions on how to make it better.  It was on consecutive questions, which I found quite clear.  I have seen downvotes on my questions that were legit, but these I found bogus, at least without users providing context.  If you don't know what the tag refers to, don't bother reading the question.

Comment: Again, you have a fundamental misunderstanding about how this site is intended to be used. If you read the document I link above, you should be able to see that. Many of your questions are simply, "I want to do this. Tell me how."

Comment: And I say, I tried this, but it didn't work.  And no, many of my questions were not like that.  This is one thing I dislike about language, the absolute subjectivity of interpretation.

Comment: *Read that document*. You *have* asked some questions that are OK. Those were not down voted. Your insinuation that people are down voting because they don't "know what the tag refers to" is way off the mark.

Comment: @cluemein I won't comment on all of your questions but looking at this one posted here on meta and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24151148/when-junit-testing-a-large-program-system-do-i-pass-values-to-methods-to-be-tes) on SO, they are difficult to read because they are long text blocks without any breaks.  At least for me personally, these are turnoffs in questions.  At least try to make them flow so I don't feel like I'm reading a book.

Comment: I apologize for long text blocks, that is my writing style typically when it comes to normal writing, I get a bit verbose.  I am trying to compensate for that, and I do admit that is one flaw with my questions.

Comment: Thank you for acknowledging that. That does make it harder. But I would go slightly further and note that with the down voted questions you have, that's not the *only* problem.

Comment: Also bear in mind that a question's clarity is not the sole cause of downvotes. If it appears that you've not done any research into the problem by yourself, or if the question isn't likely to be useful to anyone else that can also result in downvotes. Your two downvoted questions could potentially fall under the "no research effort" category. Again though, the downvotes aren't a reflection on *you*, if someone else posted those exact questions they would very likely have had the exact same response from the community.

Comment: Anyway, I think part of my rant was just frustration at spending 3 days figuring the answer out on my own (I tried file// at one point, turned out it needed to be ///).  When I got the downvotes, and then I found such a simple answer, it kind of caused me to start being venomous due to being a bit hot under the collar, sorry.  I still think though there should be a way to appeal or submit for review things, after a 3 day period perhaps.

Comment: Had you posted code, @cluemein, anyone else would have come up with that answer *instantly*. This is *precisely* the sort of reason the standards at [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) are there. Not to make things hard on you - to make them easier. For us all.

Comment: Part of the problem there is that I had to replace some of the code with placeholders due to security concerns.  This is on an actual system that is used by thousands of people, and does store private information.  At the time, I didn't have time to add placeholders, and then I kind of forgot, sorry.

Comment: Anyway, I editted my question to reflect the suggestions, and deleted the venom from my post, just goes to show, do not post things on the internet when you are angry lol.  Still though, I think that since it can get you banned, an appeal system or review would be useful for downvotes.

Comment: Or atleast for questions as well.  Especially when edits are made (which in my case on most recent question were not made until after I had the reasons explained in detail here, so doesn't really apply to me, but I simply think that it would be useful for others.)

Comment: There is a constant "appeals" system for votes now: other people voting.

Comment: @AndrewBarber Votes should represent the quality of a post, and not the ratio of the friends/enemies of the OP. (Sorry for the late react)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It seems you define downvote trolls as those who downvote you when **you** think the question is clear/good, or who provide reasons that **you** deem incorrect. Let's be generous here and say that you are correct in both cases.

Those downvotes are not something you should flag. There is no mechanism in place for them, nor will a moderator or employee take any action on such votes. (Moderators can't even see who voted on what) Users are fundamentally free to vote how they see fit, and that's something you'll have to come to terms with. Except ...

The only exception is a situation where votes are clearly (and this should be very clear) coming from a user who specifically targets you as a person. And this is the case for either up or downvotes. If this happens significantly enough in a short period of time, [there is an automatic system which will roll them back](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me). The details are kept a secret however.

And though it doesn't seem to be the case here, if you think you are targeted in a consistent manner over a long period of time, but not clearly enough for the system to pick it up, you could contact the team using the "contact us" link at the bottom of each page and explain to them what you are experiencing.

So what remains is to take a good look at downvoted posts and determine if there is any possible explanation for them. Read through the Help Center to see if you haven't missed something where it concerns site scope or question clarity. Or perhaps what might seem clear to you is not clear to others. But if you've established there's nothing wrong with your question, you'll have to accept the downvote, shrug it off and move on.

Comment: "you'll have to accept the downvote, shrug it off and move on" - how is that any different than a bully, or group of bullies telling a kid they've bullied to just "deal with it"?  Its not.  /shame

Comment: @mine the equivalent of bullying would be downvotes targeting you as a person. Someone disagreeing that what you've provided is good content is not bullying.

Comment: @Bart It can be.  Where do you draw the line?  In school did you walk up to the kid who just did a presentation that you thought sucked and tell them "Wow, your presentation sucked and I didn't like it".  Of course you didn't, because that's insanely rude, anti-social, and bulling/bulliesk(sp?)

Comment: I don't agree with any of these responses.  I asked a perfectly formatted question and was downvoted (along with a nasty comment stating they were actively trying to get my question removed) merely because I had provided examples of solutions I already knew, but that weren't what I was looking for when I posed the question (because they were workarounds/not solutions or I already knew wouldn't work).  I try to avoid the "did you try this, or this" etc. comments, and for whatever reason that cheezed a few people off.